# Remove default 'match_all' query from Elasticseacrch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

How can I remove 'match_all' from the the following query:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(es)   
s = s.filter("term", status="Free")
s.to_dict()
{'query': {'filtered': {'filter': {'term': {'status': 'Free'}}, 'query': {'match_all': {}}}}}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove that?

Answer (score 1):

The **match_all** query is optional here, it is part of the **filtered** query:

```
{
    'query': {
        'filtered': {
            'filter': {
                'term': {
                    'status': 'Free'
                }
            },
            'query': {
                'match_all': {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the spec you can remove it, **match_all** is the default:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#_filtering_without_a_query

A way to remove a key from a dictionary in python is the **pop** method:

```
d = s.to_dict()
d['query']['filtered'].pop('query')
```

You don't have to remove the key before sending the query, the server will just ignore it.